# Creationcomplete statement

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           creationComplete="init()">
```

This is my header, and this is the function that is being called by creationComplete:

```
protected function init():void
        {
            var mySort:Sort = new Sort();
            mySort.fields = [new SortField('title')];
            acCart.sort = mySort;
            acCart.refresh();
        }
```

Now, I'm adding some objects from one arraycollection (shop) to another (cart) basically (shown in a datagrid). The cart-datagrid is being modified everytime I press the button "add to cart".

I thought that the creationcomplete-statement was only executed once, but now I'm in doubt, because it's the only function that contains the refresh() and if I delete it, my cart isn't updatet anymore. Can somebody provide me with some more information about the creationcomplete statement? A search on the internet and in my textbook hasn't learned me what it exactly does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon creation complete, your `acCart` ArrayCollection is sorted; however, components bound to that ArrayCollection should update upon adding objects to an ArrayCollection.

ArrayCollection is a very heavy collection, dispatching events upon collection change.

Once bound to a DataGrid, alterations to the collection will be reflected within the DataGrid.

http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2009/03/flex-basics-arraycollection.html

> ...an ArrayCollection is a "wrapper class that exposes an Array as a
>   collection that can be accessed and manipulated using the methods and
>   properties of the ICollectionView or IList interfaces".
>        Two members of the ArrayCollection class are integral to the ArrayCollection's ability to support data binding - The
>   collectionChange event and addEventListener method. To participate in
>   data binding, an object must be able to:
>
> 1. dispatch an event when something changes
> 2. allow other objects to listen and respond to event

Creation Complete:

> Dispatched when the component, and all its child components, and all
>   their children, and so on, have been created, laid out, and are
>   visible.
>
> Flex dispatches the creationComplete event for a container when those
>   children that are initially required are fully processed and drawn on
>   the screen, including all required children of the children, and so
>   on. Create a listener for the creationComplete event, for example, if
>   you must have the children’s dimensions and positions in your event
>   handler. Do not use the creationComplete event for actions that set
>   layout properties, as doing so results in excess processing time.